# Date conversion in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, type-conversion

I have used following command to convert Date-time value in string:
Here dtpdatum is DateTimePicker

```
ProjektText1 = VB6.Format(dtpDatum.Value, "dd,MM,yyyy")
```

Now i want to retrieve Date-time value from this string/text object.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better use .NET functions, then you can use `DateTime.ToString` and [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with your format:

```
Dim format = "dd,MM,yyyy"
Dim dateString As String = dtpDatum.Value.ToString(format)
Dim dateValue As Date = Date.ParseExact(dateString, format, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CDate` function to convert object to Date

```
Dim d as Date
Dim s as String

s="2012-Nov-04"

If IsDate(s) Then
   d=CDate(s)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DateTimePicker control you are better to just use the value returned (no conversion is required):

```
Dim MyDate as Date = dtpDatum.Value.Date
```

If you want a string representation use a ToString:

```
Dim MyDateString as string = dtpDatum.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```